# Flutter build ignores --profile flag

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a production and development database. I want to use my production database when I build my app for production but when developing I want to use my development database.

I use the `kDebugMode` `kProfileMode` and `kReleaseMode` variables to determine what database I access inside the app.

This seems to work as it should until I want to release a test version that uses the development database on TestFlight, meaning I build my app with `flutter build ios --profile`. However, when I install the app over TestFlight, I see that `kProfileMode` is false and `kReleaseMode` is true, meaning it uses the production database.

It appears as if flutter does always use the release build mode when building an app and ignores my `--release` flat. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter build ios` will create a release build.

If you want to install a profile build on your phone you can use this, but this does not work if you want to use TestFlight:

`flutter run --profile`

To include different environment parameters for builds you'd like to distribute via TestFlight, you can pass a custom argument when building your application with `--dart-define`:

`flutter build ios --dart-define="MYDB=test"`

And in your code get this value like:

`const myDb = String.fromEnvironment("MYDB");`

(Another approach is to use some .env package, and have different environment configurations for the different builds.)